# External TV Screen has random image noise when moving mouse

Tags: external-monitor

Goal:
Connect laptop to docking station with external 32" TV screen.

Challenge:
Laptop is connected to the dock and I have three options for attaching cable to my TV screen.
1) VGA to VGA cable
2) DVI to DVI cable
3) DVI/HDMI adapter with HDMI to HDMI cable
If I have TV and Laptop screens open everything works fine BUT if I use only TV screen the screen starts to get random noise especially when moving the mouse.

Troubleshooting:
1) Tried different mouse and USB ports from docking station to laptop.
2) Tried different cable arrangements to the TV.
3) Tried without dock.

Datasheet:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04LTS 64-bit
Computer: Lenovo ThinkPad T400
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T400
Docking Station: ThinkPad Advanced Mini Dock Model 2504
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Advanced_Mini_Dock
TV: Sony KDL-32E5520
https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/televisions-projectors-lcd-tvs/kdl-32e5520/specifications
Mouse: Lenovo USB
Keyboard: DELL RT7D00
Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad T400
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit
Processor Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9400 @ 2.53 GHz x 2 / 64-bit / 120 Gb / 4 Gb DDR3 SO-DIMM 1066 PC3-8500 (max. 8 Gb)/ 14.1WXGA+
Integrated videocard: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620 (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
Type: 2768-12G
S/N: L3-APA1M 09/01
MAC address:
BIOS version 3.24 (7UET94WW) (2.02 (7UET56WW))
BIOS Date 2012-10-17

Comment: Could you perhaps drive the audio from the docking station rather than the TV. It sounds to me like the audio signal is not be transmitted recieved correctly by the TV. Are there any issues with the video signal?

Comment: Sorry I do not mean audio noise. I mean errors in the screen image.

Comment: What screen resolutions have you tried with the screen? Your laptop is fairly old - so I would start off with extremely low res to see if that is stable and without problems. Have you tried any other device with the TV - do you get the same results?

Comment: Tried with different laptops and it seems it is only this one laptop creating problems.